# Get all HITs with a certain status

Tags: amazon-web-services, mechanicalturk

The [SearchHITs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/ApiReference_SearchHITsOperation.html) function seems almost useless for doing any actual searching. It merely pulls a listing of your HITs and doesn't allow for any filters. Is the only way to search to iterate through all the results? For example:

```
my_reviewable_hits = []
for page in range(5,50):
    res = m.conn.search_hits(sort_direction='Descending', page_size=100, page_number=page)
    for hit in res:
        if hit.HITStatus == 'Reviewable':
            my_reviewable_hits.append(hit)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You have to iterate through all of them.

Comment: @rfornal Sorry, but please read the question before flagging as such. This does answer the question completely, even though the answer appears short.